# Start a new View Controller with search button on Keyboard with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently doing an iOS Application with Swift, and I have a view controller with a UITextField which I have changed the return button on the keyboard for a "Search" button, How can I make that this button starts a new view controller with a segue? I tried to use delegates with the keyboard but when I click it open the controller 2 times and the segue isn't working.

Note: I'm using a navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Use the UITextField [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    // segue code here
    return super.textFieldShouldReturn(textField)
}
```

Comment: But where does my object ´segue´will be obtained?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - you can create a segue in Storyboard or use a navigation controller to programatically segue.